# Update time and remaining time to leave for cassandra row

Tags: cassandra, datastax

How can I tell when a certain row was written, when is it going to be discarded? 
I've searched for that info but couldnt find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `WRITETIME` function in a `SELECT` statement  will return the date/time in **microseconds** that the column was written to the database.

For example:

```
select writetime(login) from user;
```

Will return something like:

```
writetime(login)
------------------
1439082127862000
```

When you insert a row with a TTL (time-to-live) in seconds, for example:

```
INSERT INTO user(login) VALUES ('admin') USING TTL 60;
```

Using the `TTL` function in a `SELECT` statement  will return the amount of **seconds** the data inserted has to live.

For example:

```
select ttl(login) from user;
```

Will return something like:

```
ttl(login)
------------------
59
```

If you don't specify a TTL, the above query will return:

```
ttl(login)
------------------
null
```

If you're in Casandra 2.2+, you can create a user-defined function (UDF) to convert the microseconds returned by `WRITETIME` to a more readable format.

To use user-defined functions, `enable_user_defined_functions` must be set to `true` in `cassandra.yaml` file.

Then, in `cqlsh` create a function like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION microsToFormattedDate (input bigint) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS text LANGUAGE java AS 'return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS").format( new java.util.Date(input / 1000) );';
```

User-defined functions are defined within a keyspace. If no keyspace is defined, the current keyspace is used.

Now using the function:

```
select microsToFormattedDate( writetime(login) ) from user;
```

Will return something like this:

```
 social.microstoformatteddate(writetime(login))
-----------------------------------------------
 2015-08-08 20:02:07,862
```

Answer (score 0):

Use writetime method in cql to get the time the column was written.

```
select writetime(column) from tablename where clause
```

Comment: Thats great, but is there a function that convert it into a human readable output? I getting the amount of milisecs since.. A date would be nicer.

Comment: if you don't care about the microseconds you can use  dateof(mintimeuuid(writetime(val)/1000))